# Show stock market in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)             Handles Button1.Click
    Try
one:
        Dim w As New WebClient
        Dim bytes() As Byte = w.DownloadData(TextBox1.Text)
        Dim istream As New MemoryStream(bytes)
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(istream)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        GoTo one
    End Try
    Try
two:
        Dim g As Graphics = PictureBox2.CreateGraphics
        Dim w As New WebClient
        Dim bytes() As Byte = w.DownloadData(TextBox1.Text)
        Dim istream As New MemoryStream(bytes)
        g.DrawImage(Image.FromStream(istream), New Rectangle(0, 0, PictureBox2.Width,  PictureBox2.Height))
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        GoTo two
    End Try
    End Sub
```

Trying to make a program with vb.net that will show a stock graph wondering if this works or if there is an easier way. Is there a way so that i can get the number of the current stock market for my program

Comment: Where are you pulling data from, can you give us a sample of that. If you want us to test your code for you that's not gonna happen. Have a play with it yourself (that's half the fun anyway) see what it does and doesn't do and ask questions about that.

Comment: Get rid of those `GOTO` statements - if there is an error it will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: i was thinking that the goto statements would loop the image and keep updating it from the internet therefore being able to provide a foreign exchange graph that was realtime and accurate

Comment: Sorry, it will not. Not a good plan.

Comment: you are going to need to pull the current stock price from some source like Yahoo or Google, plot the current point and then draw a line from oldPrice to NewPrice, which means you need to keep a List of old points or prices (a class HIGHLY suggested).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Trying to make a program with vb.net that will show a stock graph

Your code sample appears to be attempting to use [web scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) to extract an image from a web site. This is probably the *easiest* way to get a stock chart but is quite limited, i.e you will be unable to manipulate the data, the site may be rate limited, and there may be [legal issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping#Legal_issues).

You should check the terms of use of the website you are taking the chart from, and you may need to limit the frequency at which you request the data. Your current implementation would constantly request the chart from the server regardless of it's update rate.

> Is there a way so that i can get the number of the current stock market for my program

There are a good number of financial APIs listed on the [programableweb site](http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory/1?apicat=Financial&sort=name).

For historical day data on stocks, [Yahoo Finance's API](https://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/YahooFinanceAPIs) is a free and easy option. Here's an F# script example to [Get Stock Quote Data and Historical Stock Prices from Yahoo Finance](http://fssnip.net/1M).

> being able to provide a foreign exchange graph that was realtime and accurate

There's a good blog series on reading real-time data from [Interactive Brokers](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/main.php) (IB):

- [Connect to InteractiveBrokers via ActiveX](http://programmingcradle.blogspot.sg/2014/01/f-connect-to-interactivebrokers-via.html)
- [Capture tick price data from InteractiveBrokers](http://programmingcradle.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/f-capture-market-depth-data-from.html)
- [Capture market depth data from InteractiveBrokers](http://programmingcradle.blogspot.sg/2014/02/f-capture-market-depth-data-from.html)
- [Capture real time bars from InteractiveBrokers](http://programmingcradle.blogspot.sg/2014/03/f-capture-real-time-bars-from.html)

> show a stock graph

.Net has a built-in [chart controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456632%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) including [stock charts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456733%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [candlestick charts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456671%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

For an end-to-end example see the MSDN Tutorial: [Creating Charts with Real-Time Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh297119%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

There are also a good number of open source and commercial charting libraries.

Note: some of the examples are in F#, for a quick introduction to F# read [F# eye for the VB guy](http://trelford.com/blog/post/fs4vb.aspx).